# Pass an array in as function parameter or use array.split in extendscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm using cep (csinterface) to communicate with extendscript and I need to pass an array in a fonction. The problem is that extendscript convert my array in a string. I wanted to send a string with delimiter at my function but when I use array.split() I got an evalscript error.

In the index.js

```
let stringNotes = "2287,3474|2268,3430|2255,3398|2255,3360|2255,3315|2255,3264|2255,3207|2261,3162|2331,3047|2389,3003|2433,2977|2484,2965|2541,2946|2580,2946|2618,2946|2650,2952|2688,2971|2720,2990|2745,3022|2764,3054|2777,3086|2790,3124|2803,3162|2803,3207|2803,3251|2803,3296|2783,3360|2752,3411|2726,3449|2707,3493|2688,3519|2637,3557|2611,3570|2592,3576|2573,3576|2554,3589|2548,3589|2541,3589|2535,3589|2529,3589|2516,3589|2510,3589|2503,3583|2497,3576|2497,3557|2497,3551|2497,3525|2497,3512|2497,3493|2490,3481|2490,3455|2478,3442|2478,3423|2478,3417|2471,3398|2465,3391|2459,3372|2452,3366|2446,3366*2401,3328|2389,3321|2382,3321|2376,3321|2369,3315|2350,3309|2344,3302";

stringNotes = stringNotes.split("*");

for(let i=0;i<stringNotes.length;i++) {   stringNotes[i] = stringNotes[i].split("|");   for(let j=0;j<stringNotes[i].length;j++) {
    stringNotes[i][j] = stringNotes[i][j].split(",");
    stringNotes[i][j][0] = parseInt(stringNotes[i][j][0]);
    stringNotes[i][j][1] = parseInt(stringNotes[i][j][1]);   }  }

console.log(stringNotes);

for(let i=0;i<stringNotes.length;i++) {   //Call evalscript and send my list to evalscript   csInterface.evalScript(`DrawShape('${JSON.stringify(stringNotes[i])}')`, function(res){console.log(res)}); }
```

NB : the console.log of my array stringNotes in index.js display the array correctly

In the index.jsx

```
function DrawShape(arr) 
{
    return arr[0];
}
```

Excepted output in console :
[2287,3474]
[2401,3328]

Result :
[
[

Thank you for helping !

Comment: Change `DrawShape('${arrayNotes}')` to `DrawShape(${JSON.stringify(arrayNotes)})`

Comment: *"The problem is that extendscript convert my array in a string."* That is not true. The array is converted to a string because you use string interpolation. (`\`DrawShape('${arrayNotes}')\`` converts the array into a string)

Comment: Thank you, and how can I do to avaoid that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template literal will indeed produce a single-quoted string literal that is passed to `DrawShape`.

Instead, make sure that it does not pass '123,132,322', but [123,132,322]. The easy part is that you should remove those single quotes. And then convert your array to JSON.

See below the difference of what gets evaluated. Here I don't call the evaluator, but just display what it gets to work with:

```js
arrayNotes = [[2287,3474],[2268,3430],[2255,3398],[2255,3360]];

console.log("bad:");
console.log(`DrawShape('${arrayNotes}')`);
console.log("good:");
console.log(`DrawShape(${JSON.stringify(arrayNotes)})`);
```

Comment: And can I do this for mutiple array please ?  for this type of array for example [[2287,3474],[2268,3430],...]. Because using `csInterface.evalScript(`DrawShape('${JSON.stringify(stringNotes[i])}')`, function(res){console.log(res)});` works but the array inside is a string

Comment: It works also for nested arrays, but be sure it is an array. So if `arrayNotes=[[2287,3474],[2268,3430]]` it works as well. I changed the array in the example I gave in the answer.

Comment: If however, you have something like `["[2287,3474]","[2268,3430]"]`, then you don't have an array of arrays, but arrays of strings. Then you have a mistake in earlier code. This has nothing to do with how `csInterface.evalScript` or `DrawShape` works.

Comment: The problem is when I do *return array[0]* , instead of having [2287,3474] I have [ so maybe you are right and I don't have a list. However, in my javascript, my list work and I'm 100% sure it's not an array of string.

Comment: Indeed, then you have a string. Please provide the code that initialises the array in one flow with the call to the evaluator so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes, I will add it to the question, thank you

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't remove the single quote, thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

it depend if you want an array of integer if its the case use JSON.parse:

```
var array = JSON.parse("[" + string + "]");
```

if you want an array of strings you can use the .split() method and get something like this:

```
["0", "1"]
```

Comment: I have something like this "2287,3474|2268,3430|2255,3398|2255,3360|2255,3315" to this [[2287,3474],[2268,3430],...], so I need kinda both but when I start with array.split("|") I got an error

Comment: Laurent, your question does not mention this. If you have a different question, then don't ask it here, but post a new question.